# How to create dynamic templates in knockout?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

With knockout I can use templates like this:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'person-template', data: buyer }"></div>

    <script type="text/html" id="person-template">
        <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
        <p>Credits: <span data-bind="text: credits"></span></p>
    </script>

function MyViewModel() {
        this.buyer = { name: 'Franklin', credits: 250 };
}
ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

This works very well but I am trying to **create the template in javascript** on the fly depending on the data I get back from the server.

There is an [article](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/knockoutjs/CqnswQVZ_4s) discussing the same problem I am facing and describing a solution based on ko.jqueryTmplTemplateEngine.

Can anyone help me to get this to work?

Or is there another (easier) way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out. As you see templatoUse creates a template based the type of the item.

```
self.templatoUse = function (item) {

    var tmplName = 'tmpl-' + item.type;

    if ($('#' + tmplName).get().length == 0) {
        // create template based on item type
        var content = 'Template ' + tmplName + '<br/>&nbsp;<span data-bind="text:name"></span><br/>';

        // wrap the template    
        content = '<div id="' + tmplName + '">' + content + '</div>';

        // had it so it can be used
        $('#templateContainer').append(content);
    }
    return tmplName;

}
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/K4Rxk/5/)

I hope it helps.